# Create table with longvarchar consistently in Hsqldb and Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, hsqldb, liquibase

In my project, we use hsqldb for running unit test cases and oracle in production. Liquibase is used to run queries on environments. I have an issue with creating table with datatype LONGVARCHAR. I am already using this statement to use oracle syntax in hsqldb.

```
SET DATABASE SQL SYNTAX ORA TRUE
```

When I try to create table in hsqldb, this query seem to work.

```
CREATE TABLE A (DATA LONGVARCHAR);
```

And when I try to create table in oracle, the following works.

```
CREATE TABLE A (DATA LONG VARCHAR);
```

How can I write a homogeneous query which can work for both database servers.

Comment: `LONG` Is deprecated in Oracle and should **not** be used any more.

Comment: If you must use Oracle's `LONG VARCHAR`, note it is the same as Oracle's `LONG`. You can use `LONG` in HSQLDB's compatibility mode which translates it to  VARCHAR(1073741824).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `CLOB`

```
CREATE TABLE A (DATA CLOB);
```